# Can't remove the icon of a wine application from unity dash home

Tags: wine

Lately I installed *folder lock 6* using *wine* on my Ubuntu 12.04, then I again uninstalled it but the folder lock icon was not removed from the dash home. I thought uninstalling *wine* would solve the problem but the icon is still on dash and cant be removed.

Comment: Run this command: `sudo find / | grep folder` and reply some results that you think would be folderlock files. Actually I want to know the exact name of `folder lock`

Comment: i got some result they are as follow:..................    

/media/60848958660C0877/Folder Lock 7.2.2 Final Incl Serial - {K!llERoY512}/folderlock7-en.exe.......................

/home/avaya/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/shfolder.dll

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: I suggest using PlayOnLinux over pure wine, as you can encapsulate every Program in it's own 'container' (Wineprefix) and delete it as you wish. You can also chose the wine version for each wineprefix separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to find the actual name of **Folder Lock** which is used by **Wine**. I am assuming that the name are either `folderlock` or `folder lock` or `folder-lock`.

**Now you can remove folderLOCK by executing this command:**

```
    sudo find / | grep -i folderlock | sudo xargs rm -r -f
```

or

```
    sudo find / | grep -i 'folder lock' | sudo xargs rm -r -f
```

or

```
    sudo find / | grep -i 'folder-lock' | sudo xargs rm -r -f
```

Try these commands one by one. And check whether icons are removed or not. It would remove all instances of Folder Lock installed in your system.

- If it did work then last option is to `remove` **Wine** then `delete` any existing file and directory of **Wine** and then `re-install` it again. You must follow following commands in series:

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove wine
  sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  ```
- When wine is `un-installed` execute following command(this command will actually remove any instance of **Wine**:

  ```
  sudo find / | grep -v '/var/cache/apt/archives' | grep wine | sudo xargs rm -r -f
  ```
- Then `install` **Wine** again:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wine
  ```

That's all. This is the last option for you.

Comment: you don't have to include `$` sign. and again I'm telling you it is very important to know the actual name of `folder lock` then only you'll be able to remove it. Ok I'm editing my answer and adding some commands assuming the name of folder lock..

Comment: I don't have `Folder Lock` or else I would have installed it and know the actual name.

Comment: when i run the above command it  stucks on a blinking line..and no result is shown for long time...

Comment: Ok you do one thing. run this command `sudo find / | grep folder` and reply your result.You can reply by edit your question if the search result is too more. Another thing you can do is install `Folder Lock` again and go to `cd ~/.wine/drive_c/'Program Files'`. Then go to folder lock and list the contents of the folder, also tell me the name of the `directory` in which folder lock is installed.

Comment: the result is too long and i am confused with it..can i mail you the result..

Comment: Hey! you can edit your question and and paste your results down. Just do it, other I'll manage.

Comment: here's all the result i got:
http://goo.gl/J50ZDp

Comment: it is very difficult to find the name of file for which it used to install folder lock. you have to re-install to wine in order to remove any existing icon. This time you have to use a new way to re-install wine, not exactly the way you used before. I'm editing my answer and including my answer.

Comment: i noticed a amazing thing...when i run Ubuntu on gnome shell  the folder lock icon is gone form the application menu..but when i go back to unity again it comes in the application menu of dash....

Comment: Yes because `gnome-shell` and `Unity-shell` use different profiles to show applications installed. Both uses `/usr/share/applications` path to search for applications you have installed, then safe the list in its own profile. But I'm sure this time you'll be able to remove the icons from the wine.. If you'll follow my edited answer.

Comment: Removed the icon finally... Thanks for your help...

Comment: a sigh of relief!! sounds great.. :)

Comment: Perfect! Removed Half Life icons from the unity dash without any problems using just the second-last command(before installing wine). Also, there was no need to install wine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Enter command:

  ```
    find  ~| grep -i folder
  ```
- It will list all the file/folder with **folder** name.
- Delete wherever you  find  ***jpg** or ***png** file of **folderLOCK**

  ```
    rm 'fileLocation'
  ```
- And then logout and login and hope it would be out.
- I know this isn't the best way to do it, but i used to do it...
- If you find any better way to do that; please do share ....

Comment: how can i goto this location ..../home/avaya/.local/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/083A_Folder Lock 6.0.png

Comment: Use cd command:
`cd /home/avaya/.local/share/icons/hicolor/32*32/apps/` 
and then 
`rm 083A_Folder\ Lock6.0.png` and that file will be deleted ..!! :)

Comment: its says "cannot remove `083A_Folder Lock6.0.png': No such file or directory"..

Comment: **See, what is think is: Remove each and every instant of the image(folder lock).**
it's okay ...i think this problem will be resolved in next boot, if we delete all the instant of folder lock image.           You've to do that ...!! 
**FIND THEM AND DELETE THEM**

Comment: how to do that..when i search for folder lock there's no result shown...

Comment: did u used this command `find  ~| grep -i folder` ??